# Fax Console issue

Tags: windows-xp, domain, fax, file-permissions

This might fit better here, I asked it on ServerFault with no responses.

I just moved our whole office over to a domain to be able to apply proper permission settings. I migrated all the user profiles to the new domain profiles so that the users wouldn't know the difference, except their new usernames. Only one user has run into an issue after the migration.

The problem I'm having is that I have a user who uses the fax console to send not receive faxes. Everything works fine except that his "Sent Faxes" folder doesn't refresh with his new sent faxes. I have set him to all applicable fax folder permissions and fax printer permissions. The faxes do write to the folder they just don't show up in the console itself. If I copy the "Sent Fax" folder, delete its contents and then copy the backup into the folder it loads normally. The following day his new faxes don't show up.

I've also tested the same issues on my admin account and I see the same faxes he does.